# C dll equivalent to python ctypes

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I am pretty capable of coding in python but want to start using C for some of my functions. Using ctypes I can open a DLL and use the functions quite easily. Searching for a simple C example of this equivalent seems impossible. I always find 2 page C++ examples full of boiler-plate code and can't really tell what is happening. Or worse, .Net and visual studio examples that import all sorts of dependencies. Below is the python code that works fine including the API documentation of a function of the DLL.

> ```
> from the API Doc:
> Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion
> int Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion(wchar_t *version)
> Description: Provides the library version as NULL terminated UNICODE string.
> Parameters: Inputs: - none Outputs: - wchar_t *version - Pointer to buffer string of 64 bytes
> (MPC2210_LIBRARY_VERSION_SIZE) in size (So it can accommodate max 30 wide characters.)
> The version string, including the NULL terminator is copied in this buffer.
> Cannot be NULL.
> Returns:
> - positive value: version string size (bytes) including the null character
> - negative value: E_ERR_NULL (-10) if *version is NULL
> ```

```
from ctypes import windll, c_wchar, byref # bring in some ctypes objects
version = (c_wchar * 64)() # declare 64 index array to put unicode characters into
mcp2210_dll = windll.LoadLibrary("mcp2210_dll_um_x86.dll") # get a handle to the dll
ret_code = mcp2210_dll.Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion(byref(version)) # call the function
print(ret_code, version.value) # display results

outputs -> (12, u'2.1.0')
```

below is my failed attempt at using this dll in code::blocks

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mcp2210_dll_um.h"

int main()
{   HINSTANCE hinstDLL;
    hinstDLL = LoadLibrary("mcp2210_dll_um_x86.dll");
    if (hinstDLL != 0){
        printf("DLL loaded ok");
        char *version;
        int VersionFunction;
        VersionFunction = GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion");
        VersionFunction(*version);
        printf(version);
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
    FreeLibrary(hinstDLL);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to build and load the dll if I leave out the lines where I try to run the function. What is the simplest way to use this DLL in C? The error I'm getting is:

> ...\dll_test_use\main.c|13|error: called object 'VersionFunction' is
>   not a function or function pointer|

EDIT: ****Solved****
@dgnuff is correct.

This is all I need to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mcp2210_dll_um.h"
int main(){
    int ret_code;
    wchar_t version[64];
    ret_code = Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion(version);
    printf("%d\n", ret_code);
    return 0;
}
```

After that, since I'm using code::blocks I needed to go to the linker settings and add the .lib file.

> Settings/Compiler/LinkerSettings/LinkLibraries: and add
>   mcp2210_dll_um_x86.lib

Comment: That's because you declared `VersionFunction` as `int` (vs. a pointer to something). But, the argument `*version` is certainly wrong to retrieve a version _string_. Depending on what the real version function does, you may need to call it with: `char *version; VersionFunction(&version);` or `char version[100]; VersionFunction(version)`. And, you'd need (e.g.) `void (*VersionFunction)(char **);` or `void (*VersionFunction)(char *);` respectively to declare a function pointer. And do `printf("%s\n",version);` because version may have `%` format chars in it that will mess up printf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here.  Firstly `GetProcAddress()` returns the address of the entry point of the named function.  Storing that in an `int` is not a useful thing to do, because you can't meaningfully call an `int` value.

Right off the top of my head, I can't tell you the signature of `Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion()` but an educated guess based on the python says it's something akin to `int Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion(wchar_t *version);`.  So you'd need to declare your `Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion` variable as a pointer to the appropriate function signature.  There's any amount of information on the details of this on the web: [Here's one page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/).

All of that said, while `LoadLibrary()` is one way to access a DLL from C code, it's generally better for a lot of reasons if you statically link it.  I note that you have this line in your source:

```
#include "mcp2210_dll_um.h"
```

which has a very high probability of being the "import header" for the DLL you're loading.  If that's the case, then you don't actually need to do the `LoadLibrary()` `GetProcAddress()` shenanigans, you can just directly call into the routine in question, and the linker / executable loader will take care of all the magic for you.

This contingent on their being a suitable `mcp2210_dll_um.lib` library file somewhere that you can link into your project: that's the "import library" that is instrumental in making this all work.

The other issue is that as written, you use of the `version` variable is almost certainly not going to work as you want.  That's a whole different problem, and as noted in numerous questions, the differences and similarities between arrays and pointers is something that can cause quite a bit of confusion early on in ones C experience.

The bottom line here assumes that `Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion()` does indeed take a wide character pointer, and fills in the pointed to location with a string holding the version.

In that case, you'd want to declare version as an array, not a pointer:

```
wchar_t version[64];
```

which should exactly match the python declaration:

```
version = (c_wchar * 64)()
```

That creates an array while your original `char *version;` only created a pointer.  `wchar_t` is the C equivalent of python's `c_wchar`.

Now, to pass that array into `Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion()` you simply name it like this:

```
Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion(version);
```

C (and C++) can be a little confusing about how arrays and pointers work, what each one is, and how they interact with each other.

The really short answer is that arrays are fixed in place, wherever they're declared and consist of the stated number of objects, all adjacent to one-another in memory.

Pointers on the other hand are the **address** of something.  So just declaring a pointer to (e.g.) `wchar_t` doesn't actually allocate any `wchar_t`'s, it just gives you something that can hold the address of any `wchar_t` of your choosing.

-- Edit for clarification on static DLL usage --

From what you've said in your comments, it should be as simple as including the header file in the C source file, which you are already doing, and simply calling the function directly in the C source:

```
wchar_t version[64];
int retval = Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion(version);
```

You'll need to be a bit careful handing `version` to `printf()` since version is a wide character string, and by default, `printf()` deals with normal `char` strings.  Take a look at either `_wprintf()` or `_tprintf()` to get this to work correctly.

As for linking in the library, how you do that depends on whether you're invoking the linker directly from the command line or a makefile, or whether you're building as a Visual Studio project.

In the former case, you'll have something like

```
link.exe /option /option filename.obj other_filename.obj etc. etc. etc.
```

You just need to add the library `mcp2210_dll_um_x86.lib` to the command line and it should work.  Note that if the library is off in a directory elsewhere, you can either use its full path to name it, or provide a `/LIBPATH` option to tell the linker what directory its in.  See documentation for [LINK.EXE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  for details.

If you're doing this using Visual Studio it's all under the project properties, `Linker` section.  In the general page give the directory of the library in the `Additional Library Directories` field, and then in the next page down: `Input` provide the name of the library, including the `.lib` in the `Additional Dependencies`

Regretfully, if you're doing this with Cygwin / GCC I'm not sure the exact mechanism, since I don't ever use those tools under Windows.

Comment: Excellent answer. I'm hoping you can elaborate on the use of the header and lib file. I do have both and assumed there was a more elegant way to call the functions. The line in the header file for this function is: 
/* MCP2210 UM DLL API definition */
MCP2210_DLL_UM_API int __stdcall Mcp2210_GetLibraryVersion(wchar_t *version);
If I #include the header is there a way to call this directly, without the LoadLibrary()? I assume I need to link the .lib file in the linker settings also.